# Unable to deploy spring boot Jpa war in jboss-eap-6

Tags: jboss-eap-6

I am unable to deploy my war in Jboss which contains jar files inside my web-inf/lib folder.
I am not able to figure out how to configure Jboss to use jar from my libs which is inside my war file.

Since Jboss is using own hibernate jars hence I am facing the issue .
Also exclude module javax.persistent.api and org.hibernate is not working.
Expert suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss EAP 7, to access `lib` files present in ear inside war you could try by adding a context param in your war's `web.xml`.

To create env variable try below in terminal:

```
export JAR_HOME=../jboss-eap-7.1/standalone/deployments/example.ear(Please add value equivalent to your environment and ear's path)
export PATH=$PATH:$JAR_HOME
Add this variable to web.xml as file:${JAR_HOME}/lib/example.jar
```

Read this context param inside your classes present inside war.
Exclude required modules using jboss-deployment-structure.xml.
This may resolve your issue.

Comment: I am suing eap 6.4 and that does not support jpa 2.1. I have tried given work around but nothing seems to be working. In websphere I can do this easily . By setting parent first.